# Best method to store list of foreign keys in a model?

Tags: django, django-models

For an example, let's say I'm running an online meat shop. Orders come in "parcels", which contain various types of meat.
My models could look something like this:

```
class Parcel(models.Model):
    customer_address = models.CharField()
    date_wanted = models.DateField()
    meats = ?
class Meat:
    name = models.CharField()
    cost = models.DecimalField(4, 2)
```

So, I would have set of Meat objects that represent all the different meats I can put in a parcel. Then, the parcel contains a large amount of meat objects, as well as the address it needs to be shipped to, etc.
How do I store an unknown amount of foreign keys in a Django model?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a classic many-to-many relationship: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

An editor suggests this article for an alternate explanation of Django's `ManyToManyField`: https://www.sankalpjonna.com/learn-django/the-right-way-to-use-a-manytomanyfield-in-django.

Comment: Doh! This is originally what I thought it was for, but then I misread some things. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1):

A classic many-to-many relationship would work until you have a quantity of a certain meat in a parcel and you want to calculate the total price.

The many-to-many relationship can only give you the set of the types of meats in a parcel.

You would need another model to store the quantity information. In Django, this is done with the "through" model in the many-to-many relationship https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

```
class Parcel(models.Model):
    customer_address = models.CharField()
    date_wanted = models.DateField()
    meats = models.ManyToManyField(Meat, through=MeatInParcel)

class Meat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    cost = models.DecimalField(4, 2)

class MeatInParcel(models.Model):
    parcel = models.ForeignKey(Parcel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meat = models.ForeignKey(Meat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany for more details on how to use `add()`, `create()`, or `set()` to create relationships